# How to rsync when destination file is with attribute i (shown in lsattr)

Tags: rsync

When I run

```
rsync -azV /source_dir /dest_dir
```

I find one file with ***i*** attribute in dest_dir is not synced, with error like:

```
error: rename dest_dir/.file.3dsx3x to dest_dir/file fails: Operation Not permitted
```

I understand that the file with ***i*** is not replaceable. But if I really want to sync it, what could I do? Is there any way for rsync command to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only option rsync has for attributes is `-X`, to copy them, and even that doesn't attempt to create files with the `i` attribute.

I think you'll just have to remove the attribute for the duration of the sync.